# What does "завьюженный" mean?

Tags: перевод

What is the meaning of the word "завьюженный"? I can't find this in any dictionaries. It's an adjective, right? I think it might mean something like "cold".

Comment: See [завьюжить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) and, of course, [вьюга](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D0%B3%D0%B0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This word is derived from *вьюга*, which translates to **snowstorm** or **blizzard**. The meaning is therefore something close to "covered in snow" - basically, it describes something after a snowstorm.